# javascript: protocol is bad, but what is the most accessible alternative?

Tags: javascript, events, accessibility

So I guess it's pretty unanimous that using `href="javascript:fn_name();"` is bad practice. But let's say I have a link: `<a href="#" class="exec-fn">Click me</a>`.

I can use

```
$('.exec-fn').click(fn_name);
```

But this isn't very accessible. Since it's a click event, this doesn't work for tapping or, perhaps, tabbing to the link and pressing Enter to follow it. I kind of want to emulate the browser's ability to focus and follow a link as its default behavior allows it to, but I know the `javascript:` protocol is not recommended, and I also don't always want to name a globally accessible function either.

Is there a better method?

Comment: `Since it's a click event, this doesn't work [...]` But it does!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a corresponding recommendation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#click-synthesis

> If the instance of the activation trigger is not an event of event
>   type click (that is, when it does not result from a user's activation
>   of a button or link using a mouse or equivalent pointing device), the
>   implementation MUST synthesize and dispatch an event of event type
>   click as one of the default actions of that activation trigger. The
>   value of the Event.target MUST be set to the event target (normally,
>   the currently focused element), and the event MUST simulate a left
>   click (i.e., the MouseEvent.button attribute value MUST be 0, and the
>   MouseEvent.buttons attribute value MUST be 1). Other context
>   information of such a simulated click event is implementation
>   dependent, but for historical purposes, the interface for the click
>   event MUST be the MouseEvent interface, regardless of the actual
>   device used to activate the element. Preventing the default action of
>   the activation trigger, such as with the Event.preventDefault(), MUST
>   stop the initiation of the  activation behavior.

And an example:

> When a user activates a hyperlink using a keyboard, such as by focusing the hyperlink element and pressing the 'Enter' or ' ' key, a click event would be dispatched as the default action of the respective keydown event.

Basicly, click event is a way to go.

Comment: I use standard click events on link elements for all my sites, and testing proves that they accept both touch and keyboard interactions as well as mouse clicks.

Comment: What do you know? Guess I just need to test my work. I was used to doing `on('click tap')` (jQuery) with the assumption that that would solve it. Maybe I just need to `click` and be done with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Projects like Ben Alman's JQuery BBQ provide a nice easy way to listen to hash changes. You could keep your link as `<a href="#go-there">Do things</a>`. JQ BBQ can pick up and do things and go places.

Frameworks like Backbone have this built in to Router. You could create a router for #/go-there and have some things happen.

If you're more of a vanilla-js kind of dev, then use the window.onhashchange event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

I'm on my phone, just had a few minutes of down time. Otherwise I'd provide links and more verbosity. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but hash-changing or history push states aren't going to work in my situation. I am editing an existing application that is heavily dated but does make sue of the hash/URL. I'm just looking for something a little more adaptive than a simple `click` event.